# CommandLine for Exporting All MS SQL Tables to CSV

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, csv, azure-data-studio

On my Mac, I have a docker container running an Ubuntu version of MS SQL.  I have a DB running in it and I can access it via Azure Data Studio, and I can view each table individually and export it to CSV using the GUI, but I was hoping to find a way to export all tables to CSV en masse.  I have googled it endlessly but have yet to find the command line SQL commands to do this export, and Azure Data Studio seems to only offer one-table-at-a-time exporting.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Are you looking for [`bcp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: I am uncertain.  I took a look at it, and it is unclear to me as to whether I can use bcp to export every table for me, or if I have to do it table by table.

Comment: That was a rethorical question, imposed by SE. You _are_ looking for `bcp`.